# javascript that copies a var to a textbox

Tags: javascript

I got this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h3 id="js" class="text-blue title-article editable">@Model.Title</h3>

    <input type="text" id="testinput" name="testinput" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="changeLink()">
}
<script>
    function changeLink()
    {
    var str =document.getElementById('js').innerHTML;
    alert(str);
    }    
 </script>
```

When I click the submit-button, the function gets the .innerhtml from the id="js".
I would like the var str to get copied into the textbox with the id="testinput".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value from js element and equal to the testinput

```
     <script>
        function changeLink()
        {
        document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = document.getElementById('testinput').value

        }    
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
    <script>
     function changeLink()
     {
        document.getElementById('testinput').value=str ;
     }
    </script>
```